# How to set the schema for a table to autodetect in Google App Scripts fetching data from Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a Google App Script that automatically updates a table in Bigquery by fetching the updated data from Google Cloud Storage.

```
function loadCloudStorageFileToBigQuery(source,ProjectId, datasetId, tableId, schema) {  
    try{

        source="xxxxx";
        ProjectId="xxxxxx";
        datasetId="xxxxxx";
        tableId="xxxxxxx";
        schema={"configuration.load.autodetect":'true'};

        var tableReference = BigQuery.newTableReference();
        tableReference.setProjectId(ProjectId);
        tableReference.setDatasetId(datasetId);
        tableReference.setTableId(tableId);

        var load = BigQuery.newJobConfigurationLoad();
        load.setDestinationTable(tableReference);
        load.setSourceUris([source]);
        load.setSourceFormat('CSV');
        load.setMaxBadRecords(0);
        load.setWriteDisposition('WRITE_APPEND');

        var configuration = BigQuery.newJobConfiguration();
        configuration.setLoad(load);

        var newJob = BigQuery.newJob();
        newJob.setConfiguration(configuration);

        var job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(newJob, ProjectId);

    }catch(err){ 
        Logger.log('Table upload error: %s', err);  
    } 
}
```

The script seems to be working properly because I can see the error in job history in Big query. The error says that the schema is not defined. I want to set the schema to autodetect. Can someone suggest the changes that I need to make in my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "load.setAutodetect(true);"

More details:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load