# How to define schema in the Google script instead of using schema detect?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have been using the following Google script to upload table from cloud storage to BigQuery.

```
try{      
        source="gs://path/table.csv";
        ProjectId="project";
        datasetId="dataset";
        tableId="tablename";
        schema={"configuration.load.autodetect":'true'};
             
        var tableReference = BigQuery.newTableReference();
        tableReference.setProjectId(ProjectId);
        tableReference.setDatasetId(datasetId);
        tableReference.setTableId(tableId);

        var load = BigQuery.newJobConfigurationLoad();
        load.setDestinationTable(tableReference);
        load.setSourceUris([source]);
        load.setSourceFormat('CSV');
        load.setAutodetect(true);
        load.setMaxBadRecords(0);
        load.setWriteDisposition('WRITE_TRUNCATE');

        var configuration = BigQuery.newJobConfiguration();
        configuration.setLoad(load);

        var newJob = BigQuery.newJob();
        newJob.setConfiguration(configuration);

        var job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(newJob, ProjectId);

    }catch(err){ 
        Logger.log('Table upload error: %s', err);  
    }
```

This has been working fine and uses a autodetect schema to automatically set the table schema but now I want to define the table schema myself. I tried the following change to code but it didn't work.

```
source="gs://path/table.csv";
        ProjectId="project";
        datasetId="dataset";
        tableId="tablename";
        schema={"configuration.load.autodetect":'false'};
        
        schema={fields:[{ name:'A': type:'STRING'},
                        { name:'B': type:'STRING'},
                        { name:'C': type:'INTEGER'},
                        { name:'D': type:'STRING'},
                        { name:'E': type:'STRING'} ] };
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this schema definition

```
schema= {
        fields: [
          {name: 'name', type: 'STRING'},
          {name: 'post_abbr', type: 'STRING'},
        ],
      }
```

More example [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery#load_csv_data)

Comment: Hey, I tried this but its still not getting the schema right. I am just seeing "string_field_0".

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I try to write the job configuration in app-script and parameterize it through a function. I modified a little on my present [job.insert load](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfigurationLoad). I hope it works :-)

```
function insertRows(projectId, datasetId, tableId, schema, partField, sourceUris) {
  // Create the data upload job.
  Logger.log("Create (or) insert rows process started");
  var _sourceFormat = "CSV";
  var _createDisposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED";
  var _writeDisposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE";
  
  var job = {
    configuration: {
      load: {
        sourceUris: sourceUris,
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        }, 
        schema: {
          fields: schema
        },
        timePartitioning: {
          type: 'DAY',
          requirePartitionFilter: true, 
          field: partField
        },
        sourceFormat: _sourceFormat,
        writeDisposition: _writeDisposition,
        createDisposition: _createDisposition,
        useLegacySql: false
      }
    }
  };
  try {
    var bqRes = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId);
    Logger.log(bqRes);
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log("Table data insertion failed");
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

example:

```
...
var source_uris = ["gs://path/to/bucket/file"]
var schema = [{"type":"STRING","name":"field_1","mode":"NULLABLE"},{"type":"STRING","name":"field_2","mode":"NULLABLE"},{"type":"STRING","name":"field_3","mode":"NULLABLE"},{"type":"STRING","name":"field_4","mode":"NULLABLE"},{"type":"DATE","name":"field_5","mode":"NULLABLE"}]
...
insertRows(project_id, dataset_id, table_id, schema, 'field_5', source_uris)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove

```
load.setAutodetect(true);
```

and added there

```
load.setSchema(schema);
```

The original code was posted 3 years ago from you [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390351/how-to-set-the-schema-for-a-table-to-autodetect-in-google-app-scripts-fetching-d)

Comment: Thanks, That was it. I removed the "load.setAutodetect(true);" but forgot to set "load.setSchema(schema);". Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apps Script pre-built type for autocomplete

```
/** @type {BigQuerySchema} */
const schema = {
  fields: [
    {
      name: "Foo",
      type: "STRING"
    }
  ]
}
```

1. add type `/** @type {BigQuerySchema} */`
2. type `const schema = {` and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to see autocomplete help.